# How to share Websphere MQ QM and listener between multiple remote clients?

Tags: ibm-mq

I need to share a QM and its listener between multiple clients in order to utilize system resources.

my concern is security - access control.
as all clients will have access to the listener port i can't use firewall to manage access rights.

how can i make sure a client can only access his specific queues under the shared QM?
i know i can assign MCAUSER to client level channels, but still, what makes a client being able to only connect to a specific channel?

i have assigned an MCAUSER to a channel and set permissions.
now, from the client java JMS API, how do I connect to that specific channel, and what forbids other clients from connecting to this specific channel?

Comment: What version of WMQ at the server?

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track.  I would recommend reading the security presentations from the IBM conference as background.  Go to [this page](http://t-rob.net/links) and scroll down a bit.

Remember that the client can specify any channel name *other* than the one you provisioned for them so in addition to setting MCAUSER on the one channel, you need to have set it on *all* channels.  Channels named `SYSTEM.DEF.*` and `SYSTEM.AUTO.*` should be disabled with an MCAUSER that cannot be used as a valis user ID.  We are currently recommending `MCAUSER('*NOACCESS')` since `*NOACCESS` is a reserved word in WMQ V7.1 and later.

Now that you've blocked the unused channels, you need to arrange to map the client connections to their respective user IDs.  The way you do this is different depending on which version of WMQ QMgr that you have.  In V7.0 and earlier it requires an exit.  The BlockIP2 exit at [MrMQ.dk](http://mrmq.dk) is one that the community has contributed to over the years and is owned and maintained by an IBMer.  In V7.1 and later the functions in BlockIP2 have been implemented natively in WMQ as CHLAUTH rules.

Specifically, the exit or in V7.1 the CHLAUTH rules allow you to map the connecting client's asserted ID, IP address or SSL Distinguished Name to a user ID to place into MCAUSER when the channel connection is made.

If you need to validate user ID and password, then you would need to write or purchase an exit to do that.  Neither WMQ nor BlockIP2 validate ID and password at this time.  However, business partners such as Capitalware sell exits which do just that. If you wished to write such an exit, the BlockIP2 source code is a good place to start.

Comment: thanks @rob. this is very helpful. still, how can a client using JMS API pass it's user ID? would it be Connection createConnection(String userID, String password)? and according to your reply only the userID is used? so I still must use IP based rules?

Comment: Correct. WMQ does nothing with the password other than to make it available to an exit. If an exit is not present to validate the ID and password, WMQ just uses the ID presented which, as your example shows, can be asserted by the programmer or user.  Currently your choices are to use IP filtering, certificate distinguished name filtering or map the ID presented. The CHLAUTH rules in V7.1 and later allow other option which include "accept the ID presented by the user as long as it is not administrative" and "block these specific IDs".

Comment: I see. when would MQ use the MCAUSER set n the channel and when the one passed from the client createConnection(String userID, String password)? say i use a disabled MCAUSER for all the channels and grant permissions only the the User ID which should be passed by the client. am I safe then? will it mandate the client to pass an User ID? and if it does not, it will not be able to perform any actions?

Comment: If you set MCAUSER in the channel, then that overrides anything the client might send in.  If you put MCAUSER('trob') and I send 'mqm' as my ID, the channel connects as 'trob'. The only thing that can override the channel's MCAUSER is a security exit. as to the question of when to trust the ID sent in by the client, only when you have an exit to authenticate it (V7.0 and earlier) or if you have a CHLAUTH rule BLOCKUSER('*MQADMIN') (V7.1 and later). The CHLAUTH rule still allows non-admins to spoof each other's ID but not to be admin. For stronger auth use SSL or an exit.

Comment: Wow. so I might just as well put MCAUSER on the channel and only use BlockIP2 or CHLAUTH to filter client IPs. the next level would be either a) empty MCAUSER + security exit which validates user and password, or b) SSL. thanks allot @trob

Comment: Yes on the hard-coded MCAUSER + BlockIP2 or CHLAUTH. No on the empty MCAUSER + anything. Always put *something* in MCAUSER. Either the value you want to use or `*NOACCESS` and then let the exit or CHLAUTH rule override it. This way if the channel fails, it fails secure. If you go with mutual auth SSL, you still need to set the MCAUSER and set SSLPEER because the SSL doesn't resolve the MCAUSER.